# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 OWIN Cookie Authentication Middlewear

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

Is there a way to intercept the event when an authentication cookie is read, validated and if valid the ClaimsIdentity object is created by the OWIN Cookie Authentication Middlewear.

Comment: I'm looking for the same.  I need to add a per-request claim (it will be different than when the user logged in) to the identity.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but couldn't you subclass the CookieAuth middleware and handler, and then do what you need to in the ApplyResponseGrant method?